# Localhost doesn't work (still loading)

Tags: connection, localhost

I am using xamp. In my xamp Apache is running and MySql too, but when I go to localhost so it's still loading and loading and loading but nothing happens.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thx for your time

Comment: you have to be way more precise. where did you install you xampp to? "c:\"? or "c:\program files\"?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have nothing else running on localhost. Also you could try running it on a different port. You'll be able to change this in the apache conf.

Comment: I think that it's out of my capability :D

Comment: So I reinstall xamp and now apache doesn't work. How can I find what is using port 80?